# How can I calculate the probability that in 10 days died at least 160 cells, with lambda 15 per day

Tags: stochastic-processes

Suppose that cell death occurs according to a Poisson process with rate lambda = 15 per day. Calculate the probability that after 10 days have died least 160 cells. I am very confused, I dont know to solve this. I know that:

$P[N(t)=n]=\frac{(\lambda t)^n*e^-\lambda t}{n!}$

But I want to know

$P[N(10)<160]$

Maybe if

$P(T<=t)=1-e^{-\lambda t}$ then $P(T<=160)=1-e^{-15(160)}$???

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Is it 15/day or 15/hour?  Title says one thing and your question says another.

Comment: Im sorry its 15 per day!!! not hour

Comment: Ittay Weiss isnt homework its a doubt

Answer (score 0):

In ten days, the expected number of deaths is (how many)?  That is the $\lambda$ in your Poisson distribution, and you want the chance that $N \ge 160$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
The probability of $N$ death cells in 10 days is given by:
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n_{1} = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{n_{2} = 0}^{\infty}\ldots\sum_{n_{10} = 0}^{\infty}
{\pars{\lambda t}^{n_{1}}\expo{-\lambda t} \over n_{1}!}
{\pars{\lambda t}^{n_{2}}\expo{-\lambda t} \over n_{2}!}\ldots
{\pars{\lambda t}^{n_{10}}\expo{-\lambda t} \over n_{10}!}\delta_{n_{1} + n_{2} + \cdots + n_{10},N}
\\[3mm]&=\expo{-10\lambda t}\sum_{n_{1} = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{n_{2} = 0}^{\infty}\ldots\sum_{n_{10} = 0}^{\infty}
{\pars{\lambda t}^{n_{1}} \over n_{1}!}
{\pars{\lambda t}^{n_{2}} \over n_{2}!}\ldots
{\pars{\lambda t}^{n_{10}} \over n_{10}!}
\int_{\verts{z} = 1}{1 \over z^{N + 1 - n_{1} - n_{2} - \cdots - n_{10}}}\,
{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=\expo{-10\lambda t}
\int_{\verts{z} = 1}{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,{1 \over z^{N + 1}}
\bracks{\,\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{\lambda t z}^{n} \over n!}}^{10}
=\expo{-10\lambda t}
\int_{\verts{z} = 1}{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,{\expo{10\lambda tz} \over z^{N + 1}}
\\[3mm]&=\expo{-10\lambda t}
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\
\overbrace{\int_{\verts{z} = 1}{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,
{z^{\ell} \over z^{N + 1}}}^{\ds{\delta_{\ell,N}}}\
{\pars{10\lambda t}^{\ell} \over \ell!}=
{\pars{10\lambda t}^{N}\expo{-10\lambda t} \over N!}
=\color{#00f}{\large{\pars{15/16}^{N} \over N!}\,\expo{-15/16}}
\end{align}

> Your question answer is given by:
>   \begin{align}
> \expo{-15/16}\sum_{N = 160}^{\infty}{\pars{15/16}^{N} \over N!}\,
> &=
> 1 - \expo{-15/16}\sum_{N = 0}^{159}{\pars{15/16}^{N} \over N!}
> =\color{#00f}{\large 1 - {\Gamma\pars{160,15/16} \over 159!}}
> \\[3mm]&\approx 2.1001 \times 10^{-15}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{\Gamma\pars{a,x}}$ is the *Incomplete Gamma Function*.